# 'rafce' React.js shortcut not working in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Coding and I thought of following a *freecodecamp.org* tutorial on YouTube. I am following the video and the instructor used a shortcut in VSCode which looked like this `rafce` and then it turned into like this

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <span className='title'>Word Hunt</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

I am using VSCode aswell. What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Regards

Comment: This could be a custom plugin the instructor uses. Best look into the tools the author uses.

Comment: If you haven't yet, take the [tour], and make sure to read [what can be asked here](/help/on-topic). If you can find the answer with a web search, your question should not have been posted to SO.

Comment: restart the IDE if you already installed extension

Comment: Make sure your document type is set to JavaScript or TypeScript (bottom right in VSCode)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to install the [React snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) in VSCode

After you add the extension, restart VsCode and try Again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. what could it be?

Comment: Is there a way to change the default tab size and make it use semicolons?

Comment: @MightyCoderX you need to use prettier or eslint plugin for formatting.

Answer (score 13):

[ES7 React snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)

Go to the extension search bar in Vscode and search the [ES7 React snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) and install

Then type `rafce`

Answer (score 8):

Search for 'ES7' in the extension search bar.
install 'ES7 React/Redux/React-native snippets' extension from there.
now you can use that shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

If you already installed the "ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets" extension and it's still not working, look at the bottom-right corner of VS code, you'll see JavaScript. Simply click on it and type "React" and then select "JavaScript JSX". Try typing "rafce" again and it should work now. **Also make sure the file extension is correct. Make sure it's ".js" attached
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

- Go to the extension search bar in Vscode
- Search the ES7 React snippets extension(ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets )
- And install
- Then type rafce and press enter/tab

Answer (score 1):

In my case ES7 React snippets extension was installed but not enabled. Try installing plugin and enable it then shortcuts will work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your extensions module in vscode and search for

> ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets

. Install then restart vscode. voila!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom snippets like = rfes, for that you go to VS Code -> File -> Preferences -> Configure User Snippets, then choose JavaScript, JSON or TypeScript or go [here](https://github.com/r5n-dev/vscode-react-javascript-snippets/blob/HEAD/docs/Snippets.md) and search how to create custom snippets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have this setting in vscode settings.json

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "inline",
```

Answer (score 0):

Install an extension named `ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets` I installed `v4.4.3` and it's working fine for me.
Or you can use this command provided by vscode, in the terminal
`ext install dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets`